# Quicker way to insert records to SQL db

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, for-loop

I have a tool which inserts/updates thousands of records per hour in a database. It reads the input into a `dataTable` and runs an SQL command row-by-row:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string sqlConnectionString = "server, db, user, pass, etc.";
    SqlConnection sqlDBConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

    string query = @"INSERT INTO table 
                    (col1, col2, col3, etc.) 
                    VALUES 
                    (@col1, @col2, @col3, etc.)";
    SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlDBConnection);

    queryCommand.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.Int);
    queryCommand.Parameters["@col1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i][0]);

    queryCommand.Parameters.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    queryCommand.Parameters["@col2"].Value = dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();

    queryCommand.Parameters.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    queryCommand.Parameters["@col3"].Value = dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString();

    sqlDBConnection.Open();
    queryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlDBConnection.Close();
}
```

It's working perfectly, but it is slow. Do you have a quicker solution?

Comment: Don't do disconnect/connect for each insert. Group inserts together into bigger transactions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is already in a DataTable I think the best way is to use [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). e.g.

```
string sqlConnectionString = "server, db, user, pass, etc.";
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col1", "Col1");
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col2", "Col2");
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col3", "Col3");
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

---

For updating existing records, if you have filled your DataTable using an SqlDataAdapter you can use the [`SqlDataAdapter.Update()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. If not, then I would recommend handling the upsert in SQL. Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use Table Valued Parameter. The first step is to create your [Table type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.YourTableType TABLE
(
    Col1 INT,
    Col2 INT,
    Col3 INT
);
```

This should have the same definition as your c# DataTable.

Then next step would be to create a stored procedure that accepts this type as a parameter, and uses `MERGE` to insert or update records depending on whether or not there is a match:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpsertYourTable @Table dbo.YourTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE dbo.YourTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
    USING @Table AS s
        ON s.Col1 = t.Col1 -- OR HOWEVER YOU IDENTIFY EXISTING RECORDS
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET Col2 = Col2,
            Col3 = Col4
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
        VALUES (s.Col1, s.Col2, s.Col3, 'Test');

END;
GO
```

Finally, to call this from c# you would use:

```
string sqlConnectionString = "server, db, user, pass, etc.";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.UpsertYourTable", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var tvp = new SqlParameter("@Table", SqlDbType.Structured);
    tvp.Value = dataTable;
    tvp.TypeName = "dbo.YourTableType";
    command.Parameters.Add(tvp);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Do you have any idea on how to speed up updating existing records?

Comment: Also is it possible to not to use e.g. col2 column mapping, but let's say write a given string into col2 like "test"?

Comment: It isn't you would have to add this column to your DataTable. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)

Comment: Using Merge is not advised due to it's many issues: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Which of these issues will affect the MERGE statement in my answer? The title of that article is "Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement", not "do not use MERGE". Furthermore, although I agree with almost everything Aaron writes, this is still the opinion of one person, not an official recommendation, another SQL Server MVP has advised that we use `MERGE` over the proprietary `UPDATE..FROM` syntax, this is again, a matter of opinion.

Comment: The article goes on to say - *"the increasing number of issues I see with MERGE make me feel obligated to document the potential problems, make sure that you are very well aware of them before deciding to use the syntax"*, I am aware of the potential issues, and since most of the potential issues are edge cases, and in this case it is a fairly simple merge operation I have deemed it very unlikely to cause an issue in this situation.

Comment: Just a quick question here. I have a trigger which creates an "insert action item" into another table, when I insert a record into the one we are talking about. Apparently this trigger is not working in case I use bulk insert.

Comment: Triggers are not fired by default, but you can use [SqlBulkCopyOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to enable them, e.g. `new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers)`

Answer (score 1):

Use either Bulk insert with [SqlBulkCopy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Table Valued Parameters in C#](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/).
That should speed things up

Comment: +1 on this, SQL bulk copy is by far the fastest way if you have the schema and can generate the ids incrementally yourself

I've personally done 20,000+ rows a second for the bulk copy. There is an example here that may be of help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy

Answer (score 0):

This is slow because every insert is treatet on its own which causes an overhead on transaction time.
Try to do bulk insert by using different methods.
Whether on framework (like spring-data bulk) or just by changing your query to insert multiple values at one shot.

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3, ...)
values            (val1, val2, cal3, ...),
                  (val1, val2, cal3, ...),
                  (val1, val2, cal3, ...), ...
```

but dont concat all of them to not overseed the buffersize of the db-connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into doing with with SSIS? or via `Bulk Insert`. Regardless of what option you choose, you want to minimise the number of connections going to the db - calling once several thousand times is going to be intensive.